# Python Program - Converting a person's weight from pounds to kilograms - 1

Tags: python

i am working on an school project and i am unsure why it isn't  working. i know the program i had done is completely wrong. the project is about converting a persons weight from pounds to kilograms and being able to determine if they are under if below 45 kg ; and to determine over weight if over 50 kg ; and finally to determine normal if the weight is in between 45 kg to 50 kg ; and also should display the persons first name and last name.

here is something i did and tried and wasn't able to perform it successfully.

```
input('Enter your first name: ')
input('Enter your last name: ')
def poundstokiograms(pounds:)
    kilograms = pounds/2.2
pounds = float(input('What is your weight in pounds(lbs)'))
kilograms = poundstokiograms(pounds)
print('Your weight in kilograms is: {}')
if('your weight in kilograms is: {} < 45')
   print('underweight')
if('Your weight in kilograms is: 45 < {} > 50')
  print('normal weight')
if('Your weight in kilograms is: {} > 50')
  print('overweight')
```

Comment: You weren't able to perform it successfully - what do you mean? Did you get an error? Wrong results?

Comment: You need to return a value from your function `poundstokiograms`, at the moment it is returning `None` by default.

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

it should be more like

```
def poundstokiograms(pounds):
    return pounds/2.2`
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to get a grasp of basic Python and programming, since there are plenty of pretty basic errors. 
Anyway the correct code is the following:

```
def poundstokiograms(pounds):
    kilograms = pounds/2.2
    return kilograms

Name = input('Enter your first name: ')
Surname = input('Enter your last name: ')

pounds = float(input('What is your weight in pounds(lbs)'))
kilograms = poundstokiograms(pounds)

print('Your weight in kilograms is: ' + str(kilograms)) 

if(kilograms < 45):
    print('underweight')
if(kilograms>45 and kilograms<50):
    print('normal weight')
if(kilograms>50):
     print('overweight')
```

The main problems in your code were:

1. Missing return value inside the `poundstokilogram` function. You need to return the value you need in order to use it in your code. Furthermore you inserted `:` inside the `(...)`, it should be placed outside of the parenthesis.
2. Use of the `if`statement. There were double column `:` missing and the conditions were written as a string, you should use "logically" measurable conditions over your parameters. Such as `= < > and or` ecc...
3. You didn't save the input variables. I don't know if you actually need it, but usually if the user inserts an input, you should save it (otherwise it's useless to ask for the input, since it will be literally ignored). So i added two variables `Name` and `Surname`

Answer (score 0):

IMPROVED CODE:

```
def poundstokiograms(pounds):
    kilograms = pounds/2.2
    return kilograms

first_name = input('Enter your first name: ')
last_name = input('Enter your last name: ')

pounds = float(input('What is your weight in pounds(lbs)'))
kilograms = poundstokiograms(pounds)
print('Your weight in kilograms is: {}'.format(kilograms))
if kilograms < 45:
   print('underweight')
elif kilograms > 45 and kilograms < 50:
    print("normal weight")
elif kilograms > 50:
    print('overweight')
```